# Growth of Axons

Tags: literature, growth

Does anybody know a paper in which the growth of axons, i. e. their length in dependence of time was measured? I did some literature mining myself, but couldn' t find any results.

I'm looking for a graph that shows the length of an axon in dependence of time.

Comment: Can you add where and what you searched for? It will help others know what to avoid in duplicating your efforts.

Comment: There are many papers on that topic. Please clarify what exactly do you want and what have you already looked for. Also, please add a [tag:reference-request] tag addressing all the necessary requirements mentioned in its [tag-wiki](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info).

Comment: I've looked already for the topic "growth of an axon", but I couldn't find the results I wanted.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=axon+growth+dynamics